# Bootstrap columns stacked vertically have no top-margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some bootstrap columns and when the screen goes less wide, they stack vertically, which is great, but the thing is, they don't have their usual top and bottom margins.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

How do I get the top margin in there?

Code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-3">
            <div id="image" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + selectedResult?.result.result.image  + ')'}"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-4">
            <div id="result-attributes">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12" id="rate-container">
                     <div class="pull-xs-right">
                        <div class="left-rating border">
                           <img src="images/star-filled-large.png" width="30px">
                           <h3>{{averageRating}}</h3>
                           <small>/ 10</small>
                           <small class="votes left">{{votesCount}} votes</small>
                        </div>
                        <div (click)="ratingStarClick()" class="right-rating">
                           <div id="rating-content">
                              <img src="images/star-filled-large.png" width="30px">
                              <h3>{{userRating}}</h3>
                              <small>/ 10</small>
                           </div>
                           <small class="votes right">you</small>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div id="rate-div" style="" *ngIf="showRatingStars">
                           <div id="rate-title"> rate me!</div>
                           <div id="rate-contents">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star1" [src]="imgSrc1" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star2" [src]="imgSrc2" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star3" [src]="imgSrc3" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star4" [src]="imgSrc4" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star5" [src]="imgSrc5" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star6" [src]="imgSrc6" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star7" [src]="imgSrc7" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star8" [src]="imgSrc8" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star9" [src]="imgSrc9" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                              <img (click)="starClick(event)" id="star10" [src]="imgSrc10" width="20px" on-mouseover='ratingStarDivHover($event)' on-mouseleave="ratingStarLeave($event)">
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div id="shops-section">
               <!--<input  placeholder="try another location"  id="area-input" #areaInput type="text"/>-->
               <div id="map" #map></div>
               <ul>
                  <li *ngFor="let shop of selectedResult?.result.result.nearbyShops">
                     <div class="shop-details">
                        {{ shop.name }}
                     </div>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try applying margins for columns else try using form-group class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give margin-bottom instead of margin-top to all the three cols. So on large screen the bottom margin will be uniform to all the three cols while in responsive small device second and third column will get the margin-bottom as margin-top.

so add `style="margin-bottom:20px"` instead of `style="margin-top:20px"`

Comment if problem not solve...!